# Corrigir Bug de uma função Jquery simples

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá! Estou com um pequeno problema em relação a bugs em um site que estou montando, onde quando se abre a interface, uma função `JQuery` que foi feita para substituir o logo do navbar por um maior não está sendo aplicada. Somente quando se desce o Scroll e retorna novamente ao topo da interface é que ela tem efeito.

Imagem do inicio da interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem de como ela deve ficar:
[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função JQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()){
            $('.logoresponsive').hide();
            $('#logo1').show();

        }else{
            $('#logo1').hide();
            $('.logoresponsive').show();
        }
    });
}
```

*Onde: .logoresponsive é o logo maior e #logo1 é o logo padrão do navbar, que deve sumir quando o site abrir no topo da tela inicial.*

Comment: `if($(window).scrollTop() >1)` coloque dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Está assim pq vc colocou para mostrar a imagem maior quando rola a página aqui **$(window).on('scroll', function()** e não quando a página é carregada em uma largura maior que 1024. Tente colocar assim:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
  $('.logoresponsive').show();
  $('#logo1').hide();

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > tamanho da sua barra de navegação){
        $('.logoresponsive').hide();
        $('#logo1').show();

    }else{
        $('#logo1').hide();
        $('.logoresponsive').show();
    }
});
```

}